# Horizontal scrolling via fragments, access fragments with buttons too?

Tags: android, button, onclick, android-fragments

Something I've been racking my brains at with no solution. The simplest way to explain what I want is in this png I drew up: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lhhS.png

So I have 4 TextView & ImageViews on the first screen which I want to be able to take me to my other screens with the same animation effect if you were swiping to them. There are many apps that do this but I can't actually find out how to implement it myself. Obviously I have to make my ImageViews and TextViews clickable first off by using an OnClickListener. What do I do in there though?

I have horizontal scrolling already set up using Fragments and what not but this last piece of the puzzle is what I'm struggling on. I want to give the user a choice on how they can navigate my app, some can click on the ImageViews/TextViews which will do the swiping for them or some can swipe right to get to the other Fragments.

Hopefully I've explained this correctly. In fact the Play Store does what I want except it does it with tabs (Going from top free to top paid etc). That's something I don't want to use (tabs). I'm hoping I can replicate that via onClicks set on TextViews & ImageViews.

I would really appreciate any help! I've done this using the support library so it's not just 3.0+ if that makes a difference.

Edit: Actually while doing some research I came across something called a "FragmentTransaction". Is that the correct way to do all this? Just came across it so it's something I don't fully understand.

Comment: If you "scroll" to fragment 3 do you want to see the other two fragments in the animation?

Comment: @LuksProg: Yes that's how I would like it.

Comment: Are you sure you're  not looking for a `ViewPager`( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html )? It will allow you to swipe between fragments and you can easily use your buttons to move to a certain page even with a smooth scroll.

Comment: @Luksprog: I've set my horizontal scrolling up via a FragmentPagerAdapter so I have implemented parts of a view pager. Each page is a Fragment. I'm hoping that there is some code I can put into an onClick that will slide me over to a specific Fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a `ViewPager`. I've made a little sample to show you how to make the desired behavior:

```
private class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return StarterFragment.newInstance(R.id.viewPagerIdFromTheLayout);
        } else {
            return NormalFragment.newInstance(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }

}

public static class StarterFragment extends ListFragment {

    public static StarterFragment newInstance(int pagerId) {
        StarterFragment sf = new StarterFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("pagerId", pagerId);
        sf.setArguments(args);
        return sf;
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        ((ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(
                getArguments().getInt("pagerId"))).setCurrentItem(position,
                true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] { "None",
                        "First Page", "Second Page", "Third Page", "Forth Page" }));
    }

}

public static class NormalFragment extends Fragment {

    public static NormalFragment newInstance(int position) {
        NormalFragment nf = new NormalFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("position", position);
        nf.setArguments(args);
        return nf;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());
        tv.setText("Fragment no." + getArguments().getInt("position"));
        return tv;
    }

}
```

The code goes like this. You would create a `ViewPager` with the adapter you see above. In this `ViewPager` you would have two types of `Fragments`, the first with all the directional `Buttons` and the other type, the normal `Fragments` to which to scroll. For simplicity I used a `ListFragment`, you would use your own layout with the `Buttons`, you can easily adapt the code. To this `Fragment` you would pass the id of the `ViewPager` from the `FragmentActivity` to later use it. When the user would click one of the `Buttons` from the first `Fragment`, then in the `onClick` method of that `Button`, you would use `getActivity()` and `findViewById` to find the `ViewPager` and use the method `setCurrentItem(position, true)` on it to scroll to that `Fragment`. Due to the `ViewPager` will still be able to swipe manually between the `Fragments`.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but that is really confusing. Maybe it's just because it's a big change to the code I have now. This is what I have now for reference: http://pastebin.com/XGNBCPPN All my Fragments are separate classes which I then call upon in my FragmentActivity. I'll keep reading through your code obviously and see what I can learn.

Comment: @RED_ Why do you use that ArrayList of `Fragments`? Do you plan to change the  number of `Fragments` in the `ViewPager`? You'll need to set a bundle(when you instantiate the fragment) for the first `Fragment`(*MainActivity* I presume) and pass it the `id`(R.id.mysixpanelpager`) of the `ViewPager` like I did in the `newInstance` method for the `StarterFragment`. Then use the code from my `onListItemClick` method in the `onClick` callbacks for your `Buttons` in the same `MainActivity` fragment. That's all.

Comment: I don't have a specific reason for using an ArrayList, at the time of learning all of this it seemed the easiest way to organise and carry out what I wanted(I'm still fairly new to Fragments). I'll have a little play around with what you said and see if it works. My understanding at this time is to keep what I have but also add in your code and replace StarterFragment with MainActivity and then use the OnListItemClick part of that code again within my MainActivity.class

Comment: @RED_ There isn't much to modify, https://gist.github.com/4124674 . Then use `((ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(
                getArguments().getInt("pagerId"))).setCurrentItem(position,
                true);` in the `OnClikListeners` for your `Buttons`.

Comment: @Lukesprog: I just had a go, basically doing what you said and it's overwritten my entire app, as in design wise. Essentially though it does exactly what I wanted so thanks for that! I haven't done the button onClickListeners yet but clicking on "First page" in the ListFragment takes me to a blank page with the text "Fragment no.1" so it works! Obviously that was just your example. One thing, like I said each one of my Fragments has it's own java file so is there a way to call them instead of new classes within my FragmentActivity? That's what I think my ArrayList may have been for.

Comment: Oops may have misunderstood a few things having just seen the link you've posted. Just going to tweak things now.

Comment: After fixing my mistakes it works perfectly! Just what I wanted, cheers! I appreciate the detail you went into as well.

Comment: @RED_ Cheers! If I may I would recommend you to improve the naming conventions you use for your code. For example, don't name your adapter `PagerAdapter` because `PagerAdapter` is the super class of `FragmentPagerAdapter` and it's very confusing for someone reading your code. Also don't use `Activity` as part of a variable name which refers to a `Fragment`, when I first read your code I thought you're instantiating an activity(which would be bad) there an not a `Fragment`.